# How to use Java Robot to click Enter button?

Tags: java, awtrobot

I want to click on Enter Button when the Download File dialog box open.
I tried this, I can see it pressing the button Enter but the file is not downloaded.

```
Robot robot = null;
try {
     robot = new Robot();
} catch (AWTException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Robot class erreur"+e);
}
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What file? What are you trying to do with the robot? Where is the download file? If you're interacting with a browser, I suggest using Selenium instead of the `Robot` class. It has a much better API for that purpose.

Comment: I try to download a file after clicking on a link, with selenium it's not possible to download the file even by setting the firefox profile, so i try Java robot function to click on Enter button

Comment: Is this part of an automated test suite or do you simply want to obtain a large number of files? I think you can find more information on the subject in [this question on sqa.stackexchange](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/2197/8383)

Comment: Yes this a part of automation test, what i'M trying is to test the Download file with my app, so my test consist of cliking on a link that will open a small dialog box and asks me if i want to download the file or not, so in my test i included the java robot function to click Enter button to save the file, but it just click the Enter button but nothing is saved in my download folder.